# Why I got a unknown action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a "manageUser" page, the route is like that:

```
  map.manageUsers "manageUsers", :controller => "users", :action => "manageUsers"
```

and, it like a index of user, but provide a ban button for admin to ban the user, so, I have something like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>

    <td><%=h user.username %></td>

        <td><%= link_to 'Ban !', user, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :ban %></td>  

<%end%>
```

And the users controller have the method like this:

```
 def ban
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
    @user.isBan = true               
     if @user.save
       flash[:notice] = @user.username ' is successful banned.'      
     else   
       flash[:error] = @user.username ' may have greater power than you.'      

    end 
    redirect_to manageUsers_url

  end
```

But when I click the link, it show me this address:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/46
```

With this error:

> Unknown action
>
> No action responded to 46. Actions:

What happen? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the :method in link_to helper is to define the HTTP method to request. But not the action in your controller.

You need use url_for system

```
<%= link_to 'Ban !', {:controller => 'users', :action => 'ban', :user_id => user.id}, {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'} %>
```